# Why am i getting "incorrect signature" error?

Tags: apex

I have just written the beginning of a new method, which looks like this:

```java
public class SeekPartAStays {

    Public Class DataWrapper{
        String toDate;
        String NPI;
        String locationType;    
    }
    public void savePartAStaysDetails(id EligibilityRecordid,Map<Date, DataWrapper> dw1, Map<Date, DataWrapper> dw2 ,Map<Date, DataWrapper> dw3, 
                                           Map<Date, DataWrapper> dw4, Map<Date, DataWrapper> dw5, Map<Date, DataWrapper> dw6, Map<Date, DataWrapper> dw7,
                                           Map<Date, DataWrapper> dw8, Map<Date, DataWrapper> dw9, Map<Date, DataWrapper> dw10, Map<Date, DataWrapper> dw11, Map<Date, DataWrapper> dw12){
    }
}
```

I am trying to call this from another class, but it is showing this error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void savePartAStaysDetails(Id, Map<Date,SeekExtension.DataWrapper>, Map<Date,SeekExtension.DataWrapper>, Map<Date,SeekExtension.DataWrapper>, Map<Date,SeekExtension.DataWrapper>, Map<Date,SeekExtension.DataWrapper>, Map<Date,SeekExtension.DataWrapper>, Map<Date,SeekExtension.DataWrapper>, Map<Date,SeekExtension.DataWrapper>, Map<Date,SeekExtension.DataWrapper>, Map<Date,SeekExtension.DataWrapper>, Map<Date,SeekExtension.DataWrapper>, Map<Date,SeekExtension.DataWrapper>) from the type SeekPartAStays"

Here is the other class where i am calling it (all the "PartAStaysMap's that I am calling are of type `Map<Date, DataWrapper>`, and I have instantiated the identical DataWrapper class in both classes:

```java
SeekPartAStays.savePartAStaysDetails(EligibilityRecordToCreate[0].id,  
    partAStaysMap1, partAStaysMap2, 
    partAStaysMap3, partAStaysMap4, 
    partAStaysMap5, partAStaysMap6, 
    partAStaysMap7, partAStaysMap8, 
    partAStaysMap9, partAStaysMap10, 
    partAStaysMap11, partAStaysMap12
);
```

What is the issue here? How can i get the error message to stop showing?

Comment: When you actually try to call this method, how are you declaring your `partAStaysMap`s? If you're not declaring them as `Map<Date, SeekPartAStays.DateWrapper>`, then that's the issue. It's also unclear why you need 12 separate maps (long argument lists are a red flag), but that's a design issue rather than a syntax/semantic issue.

Comment: Oh man that was my problem-- SeekExtension is the name of my first class-- i needed to call the name of that class in my second class- careless mistake. Regarding your second point, when I try adding all those maps into a   List<Map<Date,DataWrapper>> masterPartastaysList = new List<Map<Date,DataWrapper>>();   and  then in my second class/method calling it like this:    public  static void partadetails ( List<Map<Date,SeekExtension.DataWrapper>> ){
        
    }  , it doesn't let me save, saying: Unexpected toekn ')' and Invalid character in identified: ')'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`savePartAStaysDetails` isn't looking for any old `DataWrapper`, it's looking specifically for the `DataWrapper` class defined as an inner class of your `SeekPartAStays` class.

When you define an inner class, you're committing yourself to using `OuterClass.InnerClass` everywhere outside of the outer class.

`SeekExtension.DataWrapper` is a different class/type than `SeekPartAStays.DataWrapper`, and is not a suitable replacement (unless `SeekExtension.DataWrapper` extends `SeekPartAStays.DataWrapper`, or if both classes implement a common interface).

Comment: Thanks Derek    .......

Comment: how would I fetch items in my new class. For example, if I want to get the "toDate" string from the first map (dw1), how would I actually pull that out from it? Sorry if that's very basic.

Comment: @Rick The format of this site encourages one question per question, so this may be better off as a separate question. If you're new to Salesforce (or a part/feature thereof) then https://trailhead.salesforce.com is a better place to start (trailhead has step-by-step instruction). There's not enough information for me to help you in the comments here. This is sounding like an X-Y problem (you're trying to solve problem X, have chosen solution Y, and are trying to make Y work). I'd encourage you to focus on the problem you're trying to solve rather than the solution you have.

Comment: ok no problem thanks for your help